# school or the school?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

Is the definite article necessary in both the following sentences?

> a. I forgot to bring the book to **the** school today.

> b. His home is only two blocks away from **the** school.

Comment: There's a good answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243595/why-to-go-to-work-and-school-without-the).

Comment: So, assuming the speaker to be a pupil or teacher, it is not required in (a), but it is in (b).

Comment: If the "his" in (b) refers to a pupil, is the definite article required?

Comment: Yes, unless the speaker is *also* a pupil or teacher at the school.